# How can I fetch "IF STATEMENT" condition from the database table (ORACLE)?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Eg: I need to calculate employee rating using following code:

```
IF POINTS > 150 AND EMP_Experience > 3 THEN 5;
```

I want the If condition to be configurable in the future and hence want to store it in the database.

```
TABLE EMP_CALC_MASTER

ID   |    Rating     |   Condition                                           

1    |     5         |   %POINTS% > 150 AND %EMP_Experience% > 3
```

In my stored procedure, I want to fetch the above condition and replace %Points% and %Emp_Experience% with data and then assign the rating, which is also stored in the table.

```
v_condition = condition.replace(CALC_MASTER.Condition, %POINTS%, <points of the employee>)

IF v_condition THEN    -- This statement is not understood by Oracle as a valid condition
   ...
END IF
```

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL. [`WHERE @condition`](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Condition) would open your application to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't have an `IF` statement in SQL, but you can do the same thing with [`CASE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/case_statement.htm#LNPLS01304).

You haven't said to what degree you want it to be configurable or what your actual table looks like, so it's hard to be explicit here. Oracle can't have dynamic tables or columns.

You could add a column for each condition, like

```
rating    points   emp_experience
5         150      3
```

Then, inner join that to your base table and have a clause in the select like

```
CASE WHEN emp.points > emp_calc_master.points AND 
    emp.emp_experience > emp_calc_master.emp_experience 
    THEN emp_calc_master.rating ELSE NULL END
```

But I'm guessing you want more than one possible row in emp_calc_master.

Honestly, that's getting complicated enough that I'd probably create a PL/SQL function to do the calculation and call that from the query.

Comment: Yes you are right. I need more than one row in emp_calc_master. I would like to store all the application conditions in the table and use them dynamically. In future if any of the condition values change, I would just have to update them in the table.